# Converting an Android App to an iPhone App

Tags: android, iphone

I have built a very simple android app (i.e., an app that essentially just shows pictures along with some quizes).  I am curious what the cheapest way of duplicating my app on iPhone, assuming I can't do it myself?

Comment: Paying someone to do it for you?

Answer (score 1):

In that case, you should develop this app in titanium framework that framework basically supports javascript type structure and provides platform to develop app in both platform ios as well as android.

Answer (score 0):

[You might want to take a look at the j2ObjC project from Google](https://code.google.com/p/j2objc/)

It will convert existing Java code to objective-c.
I haven't tested it and don't know how well it does perform, but if the app is simple, it should do well

Answer (score 0):

If your application feature has not required native framework then you can create your application in multi platform framework.

[Apache Cordova](http://cordova.apache.org/) is one of the reliable mobile application framework which is run on iOS, Android and many other operation system.

Also you can find much details on this [Link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_phone_web-based_application_framework).
So you can make you application with using such framework and deploy on any operation system.